# permissions.AllowAny DRF

Tags: angularjs, django, django-admin, django-rest-framework

I am using Django, DRF and Angular. Since I started working on my API I have been managing to connect and retrieve data from my db to Angular. All of a sudden today I started getting a 401 unauthorized error. In my **settings.py** under REST_FRAMEWORK I have this:

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',),
```

So at first I thought It was because I was logged out of the admin section of django so I logged in but nothing changed. IN responce to this I changed the line of code above to this:

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',),
```

After this I can now get access to the data and the API is returning information fine.

**Question**

Is there harm in setting permissions.AllowAny? What potential problems might this expose me to? Furthermore, can anyone possibly provide me with **possible** reasons why all of a sudden I am getting the 401 unauthorized error. Fiddler gives me this extra information

> {"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/1249 Scroll to the very bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Default permission class in Django REST Framework describe security police for your views. Any view or [ViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) return outside your system information or give data from user queries and save into database throug serializers and models.

If you set `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASS` as `permissions.AllowAny`, then **any** user (also anonymous) can call any not protected API views: all operations are permitted.

If you will restrict access to dedicated API part, then set permission classes for ViewSet's (define field `permission_classes` in your `ViewSet` subclasses) and views (use decorators) individually.

**Don't use `permissions.AllowAny` in production! It's not secure!**

You must create custom classes for checking user permissions or turn `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASS` into `permissions.DjangoPermissions`. [Official documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) provide all information about permissions and permission classes.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I still need to understand a couple more things though but you have given me a start.

Comment: How is AllowAny not secure?